# Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, iphone, xcode

I am trying to make each TableViewCell named based on **functions** array. No other solutions on this site seem to work.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let functions = ["Rule of 72","Future Value"]
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.functions[indexPath.row]
       return cell
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return 2
    }
```

Comment: The code you posted compiles fine (once I added the extra close brace.)

Comment: Given your error, I suspect that your actual code is not the code you've posted here. Most likely your actual `functions` value is of type `[[String]]`. Try using the exact code you've posted here (which will likely work), and then compare to what you're really doing, and you'll likely discover your problem.

Comment: @RobNapier You are correct. Xcode must have been having some type of issue. Closed and restarted it, everything compiles great! Thanks for your comment!

Comment: I don't know how long you've been an iOS dev, but if you're new, welcome to the party; you'll run into this pretty often. Also the regular step of "delete DerivedData" to get Xcode to understand the code again.